# save charts as image and include in pdf export

Tags: django, pdf, highcharts, export

I have a donut chart (highcharts). By default, I can click on the export button to download the chart as image or other format. What I want to do is not download it. Save it somewhere and include it in the pdf export.
For example, say i have a donut chart which shows the expenses of a farm. I also have a tabular view of the same data. Right now what I can do is export the table as pdf/csv in django. I want to include the highchart as well in the pdf report. Is that possible? And how?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not build-in in our exporting, but you have two abilities:

- setup your [own exporting server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) and develop save file on your webserver
- use [highcharts cloud](http://cloud.highcharts.com/)

Comment: I have tried the first one. Have setup the export server and am not sure of how to develop save file on webserver. Any suggestions on that? I am new to this, so don't have much of idea. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Im sorry Im not phantomjs developer, so check on their site / manuals

Answer (score 1):

Use a solution like this here which you can combine text, svg chart, tables, barcodes, whatever yku desire to PDF output

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf

There are samples of all if this including highcharts shown on the pages.